# Stuck with infinite loop to count tries, suggestions?

Tags: java, for-loop

So I was making a simple guessing game which creates a random number between 1 and 100 and the user has to solve it in as little tries as possible. The issue I am having is that my for-loop keeps looping in order to count the amount of attempts the user has completed.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

class prog{
 public static void main(String[] args){
  Random rand = new Random();
  int randNum = rand.nextInt(100) + 1;  

  System.out.println("I am thinking of a number from 1 to 100 ... guess what it is ?");
  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
  int i = sc.nextInt();

  for (int tries = 0; i>=0; tries++){
   if (i<randNum){
    System.out.println("Higher!");
   }
   else if (i == randNum){
    System.out.println("You got it! Congrats! It took you " + tries +  " tries!");
   }
   else if (i>randNum){
    System.out.println("Lower!");
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Also you should ask for a new input, each time the guess is incorrect.

Comment: try a `while` loop based on a `boolean` that is false until they guess the correct number

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only add to the number tries... so `i` will never be less than 0. In fact, you never reassign `i`. Try this,

```
else if (i == randNum){
  System.out.println("You got it! Congrats! It took you " + tries +  " tries!");
  break;
} else if (i>randNum){
  System.out.println("Lower!");
}
i = sc.nextInt(); // <-- at the bottom of your for loop.
```

Answer (score 1):

You loop as long as `i` is larger or equal to zero, which it will always be, as you don't change `i` from zero. You need to put in an upper limit, or have some check inside the loop where you `break` out of the loop.